# Opacity not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add opacity to three buttons I have on my site. I did have it working, but for my text that was in the button was being effected too, so I tried creating a span around it and ever since I started messing around with it, I cannot get the opacity to work anymore.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? The part I am trying to add opacity to, is this div...

```
<div class="search_option_container_out">
    <div class="search_option_box">
        <ul>
            <li>Homes</li><!--
            --><li>Agents</li><!--
            --><li>fdfs</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle to show what the buttons are doing. The buttons are the three dark gray buttons.

https://jsfiddle.net/zoue6gv7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did add the opacity, the buttons are gray instead of black.

If you add

```
body {
     background-color: #009;
}
```

You can see the buttons are translucent.

If you only want to change the background color and not all the children, you can use `background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24, 0.6)` instead of `opacity: 0.6`:

Change this:

```
.search_option_box li {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 20px 75px;
    background: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

To this:

```
.search_option_box li {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 20px 75px;
    background: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.6);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: That's because the color isn't black for the buttons. I made it a dark gray color. They looked transparent before I did something to them.

Comment: The buttons are almost black, rgba(24, 24, 24) is almost completely black. They look lighter because you have `opacity: 0.6`

Comment: Oh, I see. The white background must be throwing me off. Thanks!

Comment: And if your question is answered you should mark it as so :)

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
.search_option_box li {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 20px 75px;
    background: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.6);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

so the background receives the opacity

Answer (score 1):

Using `rgba` will be useful and will not affect the text as well.

```
.search_option_box li {
display: inline;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
line-height: 2em;
padding: 20px 75px;
/*background: rgb(24, 24, 24); */

background: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.32);  
/* opacity: 0.6; */
color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```